# threading the server socket in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I want threading server socket in python. and I found this code from internet. I works pretty good but I don't know what is happening.
anyone can briefly explain it and I want to send data from main to MiTcpHandler class. How can I do that?

```
import SocketServer
import threading
import time

class MiTcpHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = ""
        while data != 'End':
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            print data
            time.sleep(0.1)


class ThreadServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer):
    pass

def Main():
    host=''
    port = 9998
    server = ThreadServer((host,port),MiTcpHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()


Main()
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you read the documentation for the `SocketServer` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment you should have a read of the [`SocketServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) module documentation. It includes examples of how to use it. From that you can get an understanding of how the code works.

For the second part of your question, how to send data from "main" to the thread, you need to establish a TCP connection to the server (port 9998 on the same host). You can use [`socket.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) for that:

```
def Main():
    host=''
    port = 9998
    server = ThreadServer((host,port),MiTcpHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()

    # connect to the server and send some data
    import socket
    s = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 9998))
    s.send('hi there\n')
    s.send('End\n')
```

This will send the data to the server from the main function which is acting as a client. Note that you need to do some more work in the handler to properly handle termination of the connection and detection of the terminating `"End"` string.

Comment: I don't want send data from socket. I want send from args or something like that from __init__ or etc...